# POP3 - LIST returns incomplete information?

Tags: email, networking, pop3

I'm doing a POP3 client with SSL in C as an assignment. I connected to my Gmail and issued LIST. The first line of return message says "+OK 312 messages (77850221 bytes)" while obviously I have thousands of emails. What happened? Is it a gmail-specific implementation of LIST command, or did I totally misunderstand LIST in POP3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMail only lists messages that have not been seen already. Once you fetch them using POP3, it will cease to show them in any future session even if you do not delete them using DELE.

Comment: Is it a Gmail specific behavior? Or should I say it depends on your POP3 setting?

Comment: Well, it's kind of GMail specific, although some other POP3 servers do the same thing. Most POP3 servers, however, do not have this behavior. It *might* be possible to modify GMail POP3 settings to not do this, but I don't know (I have not looked into this).